# HTTPS subdomain keeps redirecting to HTTPS main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl

Been getting frustrated with this so I hope someone can help. I think it's an easy fix in the .htaccess file.

I've been trying to implement a wildcard SSL certificate to my members portal.

My main domain is www.rawtillwhenever.com the subdomain is members.rawtillwhenever.com

I built the main domain without a security certificate and just added it to it today. I purchased a wildcard certificate through Bluehost and then used the wordpress plugin "Really Simple SSL" to add it to the site.

I've changed the site url on the members portal to include https but it (https//members.rawtillwhenever.com) keeps redirecting to https//rawtillwhenever.com

If I try to go to http//members.rawtillwhenever.com (without the https) it still redirects to https//rawtillwhenever.com

I've contacted bluehost support and they just gave me this document here.
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/766

The main domain is in a subfolder /public_html/rawtillwhenever/ and the subdomain is in /public_html/rawtillwhenever/members/

When I use a http/https header check, it returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently => 
Date => Sun, 14 May 2017 20:04:11 GMT
Server => Apache
Location => https://www.rawtillwhenever.com/
Cache-Control => max-age=3600
Expires => Sun, 14 May 2017 21:04:11 GMT
Vary => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length => 0
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The .htaccess file for the subdomain is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If anyone can help me, that'd be great otherwise I'd pay for your time to fix it.

EDIT
updated the .htaccess file for the subdomain to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /members/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ members/index.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

still getting the redirect

Comment: I had to remove the colons from the web addresses because I can only post 2 active links in a stockoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific configuration, but what you're probably looking for is something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /members/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ members/index.php [L]
```

After that, try clearing your browser cache to enforce the new rules.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: updated the .htaccess code to this:

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /members/$1`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.rawtillwhenever.com$`
`RewriteRule ^(/)?$ members/index.php [L]`

`# BEGIN WordPress`
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`
`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
`</IfModule>`

`# END WordPress`

still receiving the redirect

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this as well and here is what I found on the nginx website:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

> With this configuration a browser receives the default server’s
> certificate, i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) regardless of the requested server
> name. This is caused by SSL protocol behaviour. The SSL connection is
> established before the browser sends an HTTP request and nginx does
> not know the name of the requested server. Therefore, it may only
> offer the default server’s certificate.

EDIT: SNI doesn't appear to bypass the issue, for me it's going straight to the configured server that has SSL if I try to use SSL against the default site. I'd prefer it just fail but I can't find any way to make it to that so far.

It suggests that maybe SNI can be used to allow the browser to pass the name of the server prior to the handshake. I'm thinking this is all due to SSL encryption taking place at a point where the if the application doesn't have support, it can't "talk" over the channel at all. Also, the example above says default server's cert, but in their example they have no default server listed. In my server where I'm having trouble, the main site is default, so that part is probably not material.